# Utilizando JSON no c# e adicionando pontos no GMAPS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, google-maps

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web em C# que utiliza o GMAPS para adição de comentários em endereços.

Tenho uma página na qual o usuário insere os comentários (e a página captura latitude e longitude) e salva num banco de dados MySql.

Achei um tutorial bem bacana que mostra como inserir os pontos através de um documento JSON.

O problema é que no arquivo JSON do tutorial, a latitude e longitude são adicionadas manualmente no JSON e no meu caso, preciso adicionar os pontos vindos do banco de dados.

Segue meu código:

**index.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="testeMapa.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div id="mapa" style="height: 500px; width: 700px">
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Maps API Javascript -->
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">               </script>

    <!-- Caixa de informação -->
    <script src="js/infobox.js"></script>

    <!-- Agrupamento dos marcadores -->
    <script src="js/markerclusterer.js"></script>

    <!-- Arquivo de inicialização do mapa -->
    <script src="js/mapa.js"></script>

    <asp:GridView ID="gvTeste" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="lblteste" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Reflection;

namespace testeMapa
{
public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private MySqlConnection mConn;
    private MySqlDataAdapter mAdapter;
    private DataSet mDataSet;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        mConn = new MySqlConnection("server=192.185.176.186;User Id= ***** ;database=ondli012_buscmob; password=****");
        mConn.Open();

        MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();
        com.Connection = mConn;
        com.CommandText = "Select idDado, latitudeEnd, longitudeEnd, enderecoDado from inserirDados";
        MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);




    }

                  [WebMethod]
    static public string Carregar(DataTable dt )
    {


        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> childRow;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
            }
            parentRow.Add(childRow);
        }

            var pontos = jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);


            return pontos;

        }
        }
    }
```

**E por fim o Javascript:**

```
var map;
var idInfoBoxAberto;
var infoBox = [];
var markers = [];

function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.8800397, -47.05878999999999);

var options = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);
}

initialize();

function abrirInfoBox(id, marker) {
if (typeof (idInfoBoxAberto) == 'number' && typeof    (infoBox[idInfoBoxAberto]) == 'object') {
    infoBox[idInfoBoxAberto].close();
}

infoBox[id].open(map, marker);
idInfoBoxAberto = id;
}

function carregarPontos() {



    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/index.aspx/Carregar',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (pontos) {

            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

            $(pontos).each(function (i) {

                var lat = pontos[i].latitudeEnd;
                var long = pontos[i].longitudeEnd;
                var endereco = pontos[i].enderecoDado;
                var idDados = pontos[i].idDado;

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                    title: "Meu ponto personalizado! :-D",
                    icon: 'img/marcador.png'
                });

                var myOptions = {
                    content: "<p>" + endereco + "</p>",
                    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-150, 0)
                };

                infoBox[idDados] = new InfoBox(myOptions);
                infoBox[idDados].marker = marker;

                infoBox[idDados].listener =    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
                    abrirInfoBox(idDados, marker);
                });

                markers.push(marker);

                latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);

            });

            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

            map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        }  });

}

carregarPontos();
```

Testei o retorno do JSON e fica assim:

```
[
{
"idDado": 11,

"latitudeEnd": "-22.8668838",
"longitudeEnd": "-43.307824100000005",
"enderecoDado": "R. Limeira, 16 - Tomás Coelho, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 21370-  460, Brasil"
},
{
"idDado": 10,
"latitudeEnd": "-22.9501581",
"longitudeEnd": "-43.18422179999999",
"enderecoDado": "Botafogo - Botafogo, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, Brasil"
},
{
"idDado": 24,
"latitudeEnd": "-20.1940458",
"longitudeEnd": "-44.935004400000025",
"enderecoDado": "R. Limeira - Floresta, Divinópolis - MG, Brasil"
},
{
"idDado": 17,
"latitudeEnd": "-22.878278665030688",
"longitudeEnd": "-43.2732975914364",
"enderecoDado": "Av. Pastor Martin Luther King Junior, 4667-4713 - Inhaúma, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, Brasil"
}
]
```

Se copio esse retorno e coloco num arquivo .JSON e altero o javascript, ele funciona perfeitamente... mas se tento pegar do JSON criado dinamicamente, não carrega os pontos..

Alguém tem alguma luz?

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Já tentou dá um parse nos dados e tranformar em um array?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema esteja no retorno do seu método `Carregar()`. O `JavascriptSerializer` retorna uma JSON **string**, e não um **objeto** JSON.

Para você poder manipular o JSON de retorno, você precisa antes fazer um `parse`:

```
var pontosJson = JSON.parse(pontos);
```

Além disso, não utilize `$(pontos).each(function (i) {})` para iterar sob uma array e/ou objeto, essa função do jQuery é **apenas** para iterar sob elementos jQuery. O correto é utilizar a função `$.each` (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), que é própria para objetos e arrays:

```
$.each(pontos, function(i, ponto) {

});
```

Comment: o parse eu faço antes de retornar no CodeBehind ou no java?

Comment: Você faz no javascript, logo após ter retorno da chamada ajax, na função **success**

Comment: nada aconteceu =( não sei se fiz certo: ' success: function (pontos) {

                var pontosJson = JSON.parse(pontos);
                pontos = pontosJson;'

Comment: Já verificou se o método **Carregar()** está realmente retornando um JSON corretamente? Ele espera receber um objeto do tipo DataTable, mas pelo que vi sua chamada Ajax não está passando esse parâmetro. Na função success, dê um **console.log(pontos)** e veja se realmente o JSON está sendo retornado.

Comment: eu percebi isso e corrigi.. criei uma variavel global DT e retirei o parametro de Carregar.. para facilitar, coloquei na web http://www.buscmob.somee.com/listaDados.aspx/Carregar

Comment: Objectd: "[{"idDado":11,"latitudeEnd":"-22.8668838","longitudeEnd":"-43.307824100000005","enderecoDado":"R. Limeira, 16 - Tomás Coelho, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, 21370-460, Brasil"},"}]"__proto__: Object       tive que encurtar a resposta porque excedeu o limite...

Comment: meu servidor caiu =(